Dynamically alter formulas in Excel templates with jinja2?
I'm searching for a way to fill in pandas dataframes into a given Excel template (keeping all the formatting). I stumbled upon the following interesting blog post using jinja2 templating in Excel sheets:
https://hugoworld.wordpress.com/2019/01/21/easy-excel-reporting-with-python-and-jinja2/
I was especially intrigued about the possibility to dynamically alter formulas based on the inserted content, as explained by the author:

In the case of the above the original formula in the template was sum(b3) this will be dynamically altered according to the data rendered into the template in case of the sample above the formula will become =sum(b3:b6)

Unfortunately the code announced in the blog post never got published. Has anyone a suggestion on how to implement this idea from the blog in Python?

Implementing this in Python in non-trivial. If you are willing to spend some money you can have a look at https://templater.info/, which is a professional templating library for Word, Powerpoint and Excel. The library is only available for Java, C# and Scala. However a console executable is provided here

https://github.com/ngs-doo/TemplaterExamples/releases

which can be started from Python as subprocess
subprocess.run(["java", "-jar", "templater.json", "InputTemplate.xlsx", "data.json", "out.xlsx"])

